# "Search query unable to contact the Search web service" - in standard SharePoint search results

Tags: 2007, search, web-services

What could that message stem from? Any quick tips to diagnose?

Single server farm, remote SQL. IT guys in another location, I have no VPN for access to SCAW (Central Administration Web) .

Answer (score 1):

The indexing server or sharepoint search services might be stopped unexpectedly. Try restarting them from Services MMC. If that doesn't work, reset IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Without access to Central Admin, it is not really possible to diagnose.

Comment: No, it is an answer. In this particular users situation, he is unable to access the important aspects of SharePoint required to diagnose the issue. Nothing can be done aside from speculate.